# Is there any way to make the output of clang-tidy prettier?

Tags: clang-tidy

If I run `clang-tidy src/main.cpp` I get an output format as it follows:

```
/Users/ubaldot/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/include/stdlib.h:48:10: error: 'stddef.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <stddef.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ubaldot/Documents/arduino/freeRTOS/hello_world/src/main.cpp:10:10: warning: inclusion of deprecated C++ header 'stdlib.h'; consider using 'cstdlib' instead [modernize-deprecated-headers]
#include <stdlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
         <cstdlib>
/Users/ubaldot/Documents/arduino/freeRTOS/hello_world/src/main.cpp:210:17: warning: 'atof' used to convert a string to a floating-point value, but function will not report conversion errors; consider using 'strtod' instead [cert-err34-c]
    c = (float) atof((char*)Serial.read());
                ^
```

I am wondering if there is any flag to get a compact output, like e.g. the following:

```
src/main.cpp:10: [medium:warning] inclusion of deprecated C++ header 'stdlib.h'; consider using 'cstdlib' instead  [hicpp-deprecated-headers,modernize-deprecated-headers]
src/main.cpp:16: [medium:warning] declaration must be declared within the '__llvm_libc' namespace  [llvmlibc-implementation-in-namespace]
src/main.cpp:19: [medium:warning] declaration must be declared within the '__llvm_libc' namespace  [llvmlibc-implementation-in-namespace]
```

Comment: Why do you tag you question C++ when you only include "C" headers? And clearly write "C" code. I would expect something along those lines `std::string str  = Serial.read();  float c = std::stof(str);`

Comment: Because I made a mistake? Question edited ;)

Comment: Hehe things happen ;) But still your file is called .cpp and you do use a class

Comment: Sure. Serial is a class. But the focus of the question is on clang-tidy error format, not the error themselves. These error are created on purpose to trigger clang-tidy.